# How to remove the leading spaces of the output from the command "uniq"?

Tags: cut, cat, tr, uniq

```
[root@firstcentos scripts]# cat test1
00
00
01
01
00
00
02
02
03
aa
aa
aa
[root@firstcentos scripts]# cat test1 | uniq -c
      2 00
      2 01
      2 00
      2 02
      1 03
      3 aa
[root@firstcentos scripts]#
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the leading spaces, just pipe the output to `sed` to do so:

```
uniq -c file | sed 's/^\s*//'
```

Example:

```
$ uniq -c file
      2 00
      2 01
      2 00
      2 02
      1 03
      3 aa
$ uniq -c file | sed 's/^\s*//'
2 00
2 01
2 00
2 02
1 03
3 aa
```